# Increase Performance of Image Display in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I have code that reads video frames from a script, and this method gets called whenever a frame is ready.

```
public void output_FrameReady(object sender, FrameStatus e) {
    pos = e.Index;
    VsPlane plane = e.Frame.GetPlane(0);
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
        Host.Source = BitmapSource.Create(
            plane.Width, plane.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null,
            plane.Ptr, plane.Stride * plane.Height, plane.Stride);
    });
    base.PositionChanged();
}
```

When running with 1 thread, if I remove the Dispatcher.Invoke line that displays into an Image control, I get 120fps. If I keep the display, I get 50fps.

When running with 8 threads, without display I get 160fps, with display I get 75fps but the UI is extremely sluggish.

How can I improve this performance? Part of the problem is that the memory transfer and display is done in a single thread for the code processed in all 8 threads; and the display is very slow on its own.

Comment: Have you tried buffering, as in load it on an invisible "display" and then just set its visibility to show when ready?

Comment: It seems to run slightly faster, but the UI is just as sluggish when running at full speed. If I cap the display frame rate, or if the frames are returned slower, it probably won't be as bad however.

Comment: Interesting. If I add Thread.Sleep(1); right after calling FrameReady, the UI is very fluid and performance is good. If I put it before FrameReady, then it doesn't help as much.

Comment: Doing `Thread.Sleep(1)` is basically the same as calling `Thread.Yield()` which relinquishes the remaining time slice to another thread.

Comment: No, Yield gives faster output but the UI is still sluggish (but responding better than without).

Comment: The BitmapFrame could be created in the background thread, then frozen (by calling its Freeze method) to make it cross-thread accessible. Only the Image's Source property must be assigned in the UI thread by a Dispatcher action. Alternatively, do not create a new BitmapFrame on each frame, but reuse a single WriteableBitmap.

Comment: BitmapSource and WriteableBitmap need to be accessed from the thread that created them otherwise it throws an error, so it still needs to be within Dispatch.Invoke, but using WriteableBitmap does greatly reduce memory usage!

Comment: Using WriteableBitmap, setting a Fps cap option, and calling Yield when there's a FPS cap and Sleep(1) when there's no FPS cap is working fine. No need for 2 output images. Anything else to improve?

Comment: Another thing to add: SnapToPixel must be set to true on the Image control. This greatly improves performance and quality.